# Filter my own application from "Complete action using" dialog (being shown by startActivity method)

Tags: android, android-intent

I saw 2 questions about this here in stackoverflow but none of them was clear enough and with good code example.

i would be greatful if someone will explain me how i can acheive my goal and supply a good code sample.

my issue if wasn't understood from the title, is that i am handling the android.intent.action.SENDTO intent but also starts and activity with that intent and i don't want to see my application when i am already in my application clicking on a button for instance.

I have heard about queryIntentActivities and successfuly filtered my application from the list by its packageName but i don't know how to fire the "Complete action using" dialog with the new modified List.

I prefer to use the default "Complete action using" with the option to "make this application the default application for this action" but if creating a custom dialog is the only option, it would be excalent if you also will explain how to enable this option in the custom dialog.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but i don't know how to fire the "Complete action using" dialog with the new modified List.

You would have to create your own dialog (or dialog-themed activity) for this. The standard Android chooser dialog has no such filtering option.

> if creating a custom dialog is the only option, it would be excalent if you also will explain how to enable this option in the custom dialog.

You can't. Only the operating system can make an application be the default for this action.

Comment: You probebly can direct me to the part creating the dialog with "make this action the default one" in the android source code so i will copy it to my project, can you?

Comment: @yanivps: No, I can't. And, it won't work, because only the operating system can make an application be the default for this action.