# I don't want my app to appear on the chooser dialog when opening URL's

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an action button on my action bar that opens a fixed url when clicked, it works fine, but I dont want my own app to appear on the chooser dialog "complete action using", it should just appears the phone default  browsers (like Chrome or Mozilla), actually It appears Chrome and my app as options to open the url. I implemented this code from here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/intents-common.html

This is my code:

//Manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="pepubli.com.Controlador.Ciudad_Escogida"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- The BROWSABLE category is required to get links from web 
            pages. -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

//Ciudad_Escogida.Java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.web_page){

        Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.pepubli.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a vote down?

Comment: I believe that your answer lies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932036/is-there-a-way-at-all-to-skip-complete-action-using-in-android

Comment: No, That's not what i am looking for.

Comment: I think you didn't quite catch the question

Comment: ok.. how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972404/filter-my-own-application-from-complete-action-using-dialog-being-shown-by-st

Comment: u wanna filter out your own application from the selection at "complete using action". Is that what u mean?

Comment: Yes, I just want to to launch an URL using the Phone Default Browsers, my app is not a browser.

Comment: I Think it's supposed to be an common task but I mostly found people doing the opposite thing, trying to open Url's inside their app and asking for show it on the chooser dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line from your application manifest.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

also remove

```
<data android:scheme="http"/>
```

and replace

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

so your intent filter should be like

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: browsable use to open our app whenever any link click so can you please remove this line, clean & build your app and check again @user4216713.

Comment: It's working now, i just rebuilt the app after deleting ...BROWSABLE and <data android:scheme="http"/>

Comment: if my answer is helpful please accept it. @user4216713

Comment: So when clicking the action button opens automatically Chrome, The chooser dialog doesn't appear, I guess it is because my phone only has a browser (Chrome), so, if i had Mozilla too (Mozilla and Chrome) on my phone Chooser dialog should appear again, Am i right?

Comment: Should I replace those lines too?, it's working like it is now

Comment: yes it is because you have only one browser . or you have choose option like always use this app.